Unable to launch RIDE application
When I opened the RIDE application my settings got corrupted and I disabled all the plugins in manage plugins option.
After that I tried to restart the ride application and it is not launching the RIDE. It is taking 1 minute for loading and not opening.
I tried to redoing the installation process from start but also it is not working
Please help me with this issue…
I tried to do reinstalling

Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is does not have the required quality, because it is not really a question, but asking to troubleshoot a problem. Try to read the guides here in StackOverflow.

You should have mentioned what is your environment (operating system, Python, wxPython and RIDE versions).
With RIDE closed, you can see if there is a backup of the configuration file, on Windows at, %APPDATA%\\RobotFramework\\ride\\settings.cfg, on other systems at,~/.robotframework/ride/settings.cfg. If there is, you can make a copy of that file to other location, because you will delete the directory ride (or just the settings.cfg file). Then try to start RIDE. If it worked, you can close RIDE and copy the settings you want from the backed-up file to the new settings.cfg file.
You should take a look at the project page here, where you can see the links for "support", like the Forum.
